# What exactly does split do in the sink() function?

Tags: r, split, sink

What exactly does split do in the `sink()` function? No website or video seems to explain it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`?sink`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html):

```
   split: logical: if 'TRUE', output will be sent to the new sink and
          to the current output stream, like the Unix program 'tee'.
```

Normally, `sink` gives you the user no output, sending it all to a file. With `split=TRUE`, it gives you all of the output (seemingly normal) *and* dumps the output to the file.

```r
# non-split behavior
sink("quux1.txt")
1+2
print("hello")
sink(NULL)
readLines("quux1.txt")
# [1] "[1] 3"         "[1] \"hello\""

# split behavior
sink("quux2.txt", split = TRUE)
1+3
# [1] 4
print("hello again")
# [1] "hello again"
sink(NULL)
readLines("quux2.txt")
# [1] "[1] 4"               "[1] \"hello again\""
```